# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).look_up_term is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a simple search bar which calls the javascript function. The ajax in js calls the web api controller method.
However I am stuck at the js code due to a browser warning.

Here is my html.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                            {
                                <p>

                                  @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="$('#searchForm').look_up_term()">Search!</button>
                                </p>
                            }

//Here is my Java script code
```

here is my js code

```
function look_up_term() {
        var search = {};
        Query.name = document.getElementById("SearchString").value;

        $.ajax({

            URL: '@Url.Action("Search","Controller")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(Query.name),
            success: function (data) {

                alert("Search Results");
            }
        })
    }
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).look_up_term is not a function
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):35)
>   onclick @ (index):35

Please advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Remove `$()` from inline click handler. Just use `look_up_term()`

Comment: It's worth saying that looking at your server-side code is pointless when debugging Javascript. It's the code that the browser receives that matters.

Comment: because `$(...).look_up_term` isn't a function.

Comment: @Satpal `@using (Html.BeginForm())` etc. and `'@Url.Action("Search","Controller")'`. It's C#.

Comment: @lonesomeday, those are Important in question context. At least op provide the required information

Comment: @Satpal Not as it's a Javascript error. Confusion between server-side and client-side code is a common problem.

Comment: "Remove $() from inline click handler. Just use look_up_term()". This worked for me.Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "`$('#searchForm').`" leaving only `"look_up_term()"`. `"$('#searchForm').look_up_term()"` isn't a function as the error rightly tells you.